# AWS CLI filter OR logic

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, ec2-api-tools

I am trying to retrieve a list of servers using the AWS CLI tools.
I have 2 groups of servers, 1 will have the string "mind" in the Name tag, another group will have the string "intelligence" in the Name tag.

I can filter the output of DescribeInstances using wildcards but can I return instances that contain mind OR intelligence? in the Name?

Currently I have to run the command twice replacing the filter Value.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can supply multiple values for a tag.  I think something like this would work for you:

```
aws ec2 describe-instances --filters Name=tag:Name,Values=mind,intelligence
```